# XCode debug breakpoints not showing variables values

Tags: xcode, xcode7

I'm having the following issue in one of my projects:
[Breakpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoKxk.png)

Some things that I've already checked:
- Build Configuration is on Debug
- Optimization Level on Debug is None

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with GoogleMaps:
https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8524&q=apitype%3AIosSDK&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Internal%20Stars

Use a bridging header and

```
#import GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h
```

instead of

```
import GoogleMaps
```

on your Swift code.

Comment: You are a star. I was looking at this for a very long time. Most solutions blame Fabric/Crashlytics for this problem, but in my case it was GoogleMaps. I hope apple fixes this bug soon.